# Python : Split datetime dates on a weekly basis

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have dataset containing EOD OHLC for Banknifty Index of India's National Stock Exchange.

Goal : I want to split OHLC data on a weekly basis.

You can get the relevant data using the below code:

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date

bankniftydata = get_history(symbol='BANKNIFTY',start=date(2016,5,30),end=date(2016,6,10),index=True)

print(bankniftydata)
```

I have downloaded this data as a `.csv` file and converted to `datetime` format using below code:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Below is the output

[image]

I also have tried this below code to split the above dataset on a weekly basis but I am unable to split the generated list into weekly datasets or a `DataFrame` which I can manipulate :

```
weeks = [g for n, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='W'))]
print((weeks))
```

Below is the output of above code:

[image]

Comment: your weeks is laready a list weekly dataframes. No?

Comment: Is the output 2 not the answer that you want?

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I think that the output 2 is the answer, the following code gives the result in the form of `DataFrames`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date

bankniftydata = get_history(symbol='BANKNIFTY',start=date(2016,5,30),end=date(2016,6,10),index=True)

df = bankniftydata.reset_index()

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
display(df.head(2))
weeks = set(list(df["Date"].dt.week))

for i in weeks:
    df_of_that_week = df[df["Date"].dt.week == i]
    display(df_of_that_week)
```

The output is as follows:

```
    Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Turnover
0   2016-05-30  17580.85    17666.05    17484.8     17520.65    96747582    2.371690e+10
1   2016-05-31  17615.10    17648.25    17462.2     17620.90    115964022   3.491600e+10

    Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Turnover
0   2016-05-30  17580.85    17666.05    17484.80    17520.65    96747582    2.371690e+10
1   2016-05-31  17615.10    17648.25    17462.20    17620.90    115964022   3.491600e+10
2   2016-06-01  17670.85    17670.85    17392.85    17423.45    99164561    2.547940e+10
3   2016-06-02  17405.15    17596.40    17350.45    17567.80    78335336    2.242660e+10
4   2016-06-03  17657.20    17762.05    17649.05    17680.80    89366456    2.670520e+10

    Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Turnover
5   2016-06-06  17710.45    17754.15    17636.90    17671.40    81251372    2.190330e+10
6   2016-06-07  17796.55    18000.95    17713.35    17948.15    167578972   4.195310e+10
7   2016-06-08  17976.25    17995.80    17855.20    17946.80    123360967   2.819240e+10
8   2016-06-09  17955.80    17986.15    17801.55    17887.70    107528433   2.437910e+10
9   2016-06-10  17830.20    18051.50    17815.25    17828.60    94174779    2.392430e+10
```

Also, based on the code for Output 2, the `DataFrames` can be accessed and modified as follows:

```py
weeks = [g for n, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='W'))]
for df_of_the_week in weeks:
    display(df_of_the_week)
    # Perform any operation on df_of_the_week here
```